Manipulation of queries with NHibernate and FluentNHibernate of older versions on .Net Framework 4.5.1
I am working on an old project and we need to make some adjustments. It is on .Net 4.5.1 with NHibernate 3.1.0.4000 and FluentNHibernate 1.2.0.0. I haven't considered the option to update them yet since they are included as dll's and not nugets so I will need to research how to do that and it can potentially break existing code.
The code is as follows:
Command commandAlias = null;
var q = QueryOver.Of<Payment>()
    .JoinAlias(x => x.Command, () => commandAlias)
    .Where(x => x.PaymentDate >= startOfPeriod && x.PaymentDate <= endOfPeriod)
    .Where(x => x.Command != null);

var query = session.QueryOver<Command>()
    .Where(x => x.IssueDate >= startOfPeriod && x.IssueDate <= endOfPeriod)
    .Where(x => x.CommandStatus != CommandStatus.Revoked && x.CommandStatus != CommandStatus.Payed);

//Some if clauses that filter more things like a command's organization if any and others

var data = query.WithSubquery.WhereProperty(x => x.RowId).NotIn(q.Select(x => x.Command.RowId))
    .List();

The way the database entities are structured the Command does not have a list of Payments. Only Payments have a foreign key of the Command they are related to.
As it is now it fetches only Commands that have no Payments. But Commands and Payments have an Amount property and we want to include Commands whose Payments sum of amounts is less than of the amount of the Command. To find Commands that have been partly paid or not paid at all.
I did my research, I recruited ChatGPT, some progress there but ultimately not something that worked.
The difficulty lies in that the libraries are old and they don't have many helping features of latest versions.
Thanks to anyone who takes a look at this and any help would be greatly appreciated.
Ok since I need to write this "What I've tried so far" segment I will paste the latest code generated with the help of gpt that didn't work.
Payment paymentAlias = null;
Command commandAlias = null;

var query = session.QueryOver<Command>(() => commandAlias)
    .Where(x => x.IssueDate >= startOfPeriod && x.IssueDate <= endOfPeriod)
    .Where(x => x.CommandStatus != CommandStatus.Revoked &&
                x.CommandStatus != CommandStatus.Payed);

var paymentSubquery = QueryOver.Of<Payment>(() => paymentAlias)
    .Where(p => p.Command.RowId == commandAlias.RowId)
    .Select(Projections.Sum<Payment>(p => p.PaidAmount));

var disjunction = Restrictions.Disjunction()
    .Add(Subqueries.WhereProperty(() => commandAlias.Amount).Gt(paymentSubquery))
    .Add(Subqueries.WhereNotExists(paymentSubquery));

var data = query
    .Where(disjunction)
    .Fetch(x => x.DepartmentFrom).Eager
    .Fetch(x => x.FinalizedCommitment).Eager
    .Fetch(x => x.FinalizedCommitment.Kae).Eager
    .List();

It compiled but I got an error at runtime saying "could not resolve property: commandAlias of: Command" on the line that fetched the data.

Does updating the libraries fix the problem?

@mxmissile I haven't tried it yet as I am not sure how to go about it since it is an old project with dll's instead of nugets.

You are using source control right? Just remove the reference to the old DLL and then use nuget to add the latest nhibernate, worst case scenario you can roll back your changes using your source control.
